# Sequential Rule Mining using Apriori Algorithm and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apriori

I am performing Sequential Rule Mining using Apriori Algorithm and FPA, I have the dataset in excel as shown below, I want to know, how should I load my data into pandas dataframe what I am using is the following read_excel command, but the data contains ---> between items and lies in single column as shown below.

How should I load and perform Pattern Mining.

Comment: Looks OK here. Have you double-checked indentations? Same number of spaces, not mixing tabs and spaces and so on?

Comment: I can tell from edit mode that you are mixing tabs and spaces, instead use spaces only

Comment: @Chris_Rands, you are right, I fixed it, indentation error. Can you please check for one more, where I am mixing, when I communicate with the bot, it just gives- "the following query is not found, please try with other messages" as output.

Comment: always, otherwise it was working fine

Comment: Is possible use `df = df.join(df['Activity Sequence'].str.split('---->', expand=True))` ?

Comment: that works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`message` is string type, and `elif "what is" in message:` seems to be correct in syntax.
Have you checked whether the indentation is correct? Sometimes the bug can be a very simple thing..