# Make separate columns for Date, Month, year, hour , minute , second from a single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In my pandas dataframe, my Data time column is of the following shape, how can i extract the Y, M, D, H, M, Secs from the column.
I am using this to first convert it into datetime format.

```
import datetime as dt
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['YMD-Time'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%-m%-d%-H%-M%-S'))
```

They seems to be separated by tab. Create separate columns for Date, Month, year, hour , minute , second

Comment: Do you want `df = df.join(df['YMD-Time'].str.split())` ?

Comment: on a sidenote. Why would you wand year etc in different columns, instead of as a `datetime` object?

Comment: No, I will at the end delete the column, YDM-Time and keep only separate columns for Y,M,D,H,MS.

Comment: @MaartenFabré I will use these as feature and also do EDA based on these specific columns

Comment: The format of your `strptime` is wrong. I would also use (`pandas.to_datetime`)[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html] instead of `datetime.strptime`: `pd.to_datetime(df['YMD-Time'], format=format='%Y\t%m\t%d\t%H\t%M\t%S')`

Comment: @MaartenFabré, I was doing the same, this should work. Although, I got my answer, many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for DataFrame, get columns and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df1 = df['YMD-Time'].str.split(expand=True)
df1.columns = ['Y', 'M', 'D', 'H', 'M', 'Secs']
df = df.join(df1)
```

Comment: I want another help in reading a data file, its about implementation of Apriori algorithm and I am not sure, how should I load my data for the same, it consists of ----> (this symbol) between product association, I will make the changes in the edit, Can I ask?

Comment: @Shivam - it seems this is another question, no connection with this solution. So better is create new question.

Comment: here is the link to the question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279902/sequential-rule-mining-using-apriori-algorithm-and-pandas

Comment: I could not create, so edited one question,can you please look over that?

Comment: @Shivam - yes, sure. Is same number of `--->` symbols in each row?